# Joomla - VirtueMart 1.x > Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, database, importexport

I got a project where a client who is running a relatively big e-commerce is planing to switch from Joomla's VirtueMart 1.1 to Magento 2.0.

What is the best way to export products/customers/discounts/reviews to Magento 2.0?
Are there any tools that work available or should I start writing PHP script which would map everything in CSV ?

Thank you for any info regarding this issue.

Comment: There are websites like Cart2Cart which allow for certain transfer, but I'm not sure they do it for Joomla. But if you have to write your own code, there are tons of tutorials out there, although the concepts might be different in Joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research I found plugin called [VirtueMart to Magento](http://goo.gl/Bs3Fmf) for migration of VirtueMart 1.x, 2.x to Magento 2.

It can be bit expensive, specially for bigger shops because it's limited by number of entities, but as much as I tested it, it migrates all the needed fields (customers, reviews, categories, orders, products).